# transformation for my self

Tags: integration, measure-theory, borel-measures

I am trying to prove this equation of integral transformation with Borel measure. But so far have no idea. Can you help me how to start.
Suppose $(X, A, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f: X\to [0,\infty]$ an $A$-measurable function. Let $\nu$ be a Borel measure on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\nu(K)<\infty$ for any compact set $K$ in $[0,\infty)$. Show that

$$\int_X \nu([ 0 ,f(x))\;\mu(dx) = \int_0^\infty\mu(\{\ x\in X \ | f(x)>t\})\;\nu(dt).$$

Comment: Please use mathjax, it makes everyone’s life easier: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

This is often called the layer-cake representation. Compute

\begin{align*}
\int_{X} \nu([0,f(x))\, \mu(dx) &= \int_{X} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[0, f(x))}\, \nu(dt)\, \mu(dx) \\
&\overset{(i)}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{X} \mathbb{1}_{[0,f(x))}\, \mu(dx)\, \nu(dt) \\
&\overset{(ii)}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{X} \mathbb{1}_{\{x\, |\, f(x) > t \}}\, \mu(dx)\, \nu(dt) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu(\{x \, | \, f(x)>t \})\, \nu(dt).
\end{align*}

Step $(i)$ follows from Tonelli's (Fubini-Tonelli)  theorem (it applies as (a) $\mathbb{1}_{[0,f(x))}$ is measurable and non-negative and (b) $\mu \otimes \nu$ is $\sigma$-finite), while step $(ii)$ follows since $\mathbb{1}_{\{x\, |\, f(x) > t \}} = \mathbb{1}_{[0,f(x))}$.

---

**NOTE:** Sometimes you may see the notation $\mathbb{1}_{L(f;t)(x)} := \mathbb{1}_{\{x\, |\, f(x) > t \}}$ instead (cf.[Layer cake representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation))

Let us know in the comments if there are any questions.

Comment: @MovahediNajafabadi, yes the characteristic/indicator function, so could have used $\mathcal{1}$ instead, i.e. $\nu([0,f(x)[) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[0,f(x)[}\, \nu(dt)$.

Comment: No, nothing to do with Laplace transforms. Sorry for the confusion. It is just notation you might see sometimes. I've updated the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered, however I'd like to ask how to prove, that $1_{[0,f(x)[} (t)$ is measurable since this is required for using Tonelli and therefore prove that given equality. We want to show that for every $C\in B[0,\infty]$ following holds: $(1_{[0,f(x)[})^{-1} (C) \in A $ x $B[0,\infty[$..but I'm struggling with this..